# Why does my worker thread not receive this signal?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I have my main thread which is in charge with the GUI and my worker thread which is in charge with doing stuff with my webcam.

I am able to emit a signal from my main thread to my webcam thread, but it never receives it! Could somebody explain me why?

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    setThreadsAndObj();
    setConnects();
    startCamera();

}

void MainWindow::setThreadsAndObj()
{
    cameraClassPtr = new cameraClass();
    cameraThread = new QThread();

}

void MainWindow::setConnects()
{

   ....

    connect(this, &MainWindow::savePicture, cameraClassPtr, &cameraClass::takePicture);


}


void MainWindow::startCamera()
{

    //camera start
    connect( cameraThread, &QThread::started, cameraClassPtr, &cameraClass::getVideoFrame );
    connect( cameraThread, &QThread::finished, cameraClassPtr, &QThread::deleteLater );
    connect( cameraThread, &QThread::finished, cameraThread, &QThread::deleteLater );
    //receive camera frames
    connect(cameraClassPtr, &cameraClass::videoFrameToGui, this, &MainWindow::updateCameraStream);


    //start threads
    cameraClassPtr->moveToThread(cameraThread);
    cameraThread->start();

}


void MainWindow::foo()
{
       emit savePicture();
}


void cameraClass::takePicture()
{

    qDebug()<<"camera class received signal";   //THIS NEVER GETS PRINTED

}
```

Could someone explain me why my signal is never received and "camera class received signal" is never printed and how to solve this?

Comment: try change `cameraThread = new QThread();` to `cameraThread = new QThread(this);`

Comment: @eyllanesc what is the difference?

Comment: @eyllanesc solved it. I have a while 1 loop in my worker thread. I had to add QApplication::processEvents(); in that while loop. Sorry for making you lose your time.

Comment: @derM there you go. Feel free to comment anything about my post! That way  learn something new from it, rather than me just sharing how stupid my mistake was.

Comment: My understanding is not deep enough to judge anything, but those are the usual two options: It is worthy an answer or not. Thank you for providing the answer to this problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this loop in my worker thread:

```
...
static cv::VideoCapture cap(-1);
if( !cap.isOpened() )
{
    qDebug()<< "Could not initialize capturing...\n";
}

qDebug()<<"starting live camera";
cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,240);
cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,320);

while(1)
{
    cap >> imgFrame;

    int fd = open("/home/John/Desktop/mainImglock.txt", O_RDWR |O_CREAT, 0666);
    int rc = flock(fd, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB);
    if(rc==0)
    {
        cv::imwrite("/home/John/Desktop/camera.jpg", imgFrame);
    }
    flock(fd, LOCK_UN);
    close(fd);
}
```

I solved the issue by adding: `QApplication::processEvents();` in the while(1) loop, so that the event loop isn't hanging.

Answer (score 0):

You need to subclass QThread and call QThread::exec(); in order to process events in this thread.